# HTML 5 Canvas - Realize smooth scrolling per button

Tags: html, canvas, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I've been google'ing for some time but I can't find a good solution for my problem.

I have a canvas which contains several images. Via a "left" and "right" button I want to scroll smoothly and horizontally thorugh these images. I guess there must be a way to kind of set the focus of the canvas. I tried `translate` which works fine but I don't want to "jump" to the next section, I want a smooth scrolling...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found a way... pretty basic though.

```
function animate() {

draw();

if(globalVar<300){
    globalVar++;
    setTimeout("animate();", 100);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

For smooth animations in a canvas you need to use the `requestAnimationFrame` method (http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a job for [Greensock JS tweening library](http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/). It can tween any property that you can expose of any object.

The documentation is very good and there are lots of resourced there to get you started. You can also ask questions about what you are trying to do on the forum.

I used `TweenMax` for years as a flash developer and I am now starting to use it in JS development.

As per @devnull69 answer, it also utilizes `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: seems nice. do you have by any chance some example code for me?

Comment: There's lots of code on that link I provided, he practically takes you through all the steps to get it working and how to change properties etc.